# How can I find a word and replace it with itself but with a few things different in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to edit a word file. Let's say there's a few `John:`s in the file and I want to change it to `#John#`s. But the `John` part isn't known beforehand.

So, what I want is finding the word using `:` then selecting the whole word with `(*{1,})` and then replacing it with the same word it found but now instead of a `:` at the end, there will be a `#` at the end and at the start. So like this:

Before

```
John:
Emma:
Fred:
```

After:

```
#John#
#Emma#
#Fred#
```

Is this doable with Microsoft Word?

Comment: Guessing this might not be possible in Word, but its VERY possible in a plaintext (*.txt) file using various tools. I think this is called 'expressions' string replacement. I'm guessing you could do this easily in Windows by copying all text, pasting into Notepad++ then using its magic. There is even a portable Notepad++
https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/searching/

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. I can simply use "Find What Text" option under "special". The problem is it also adds the ":" as well but I can remove it I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okie dokie, found a way to do it.

The `(*{1,})`: in the find section finds all the words that has a `:` in it. And placing `#&` (Find What Text option under the Special) copy pastes whatever found to the replace section.

It should look something like this:

- Find what: `(*{1,}):`
  (wildcard on)
- Replace with: `#^&#`

The only problem is since `:` is also in the found word, it's also included in the outcome. Easiest way to fixing it is searching for `:#` and replacing it with `#`.

As for the paragraph issue, adding `^p` (Paragraph Mark option under Special) finds the paragraphs. So adding it in "Find what:" finds the start of the next paragraph. Simply removing that in "replace with" fixes it. So, it should look something like this:

- Find what: `#^p`
- Replace with: `#`

Comment: Great! Now that you have self-solved your question, please be sure to check it off as the answer. That is the checkmark near the upper left part of the answer; right below the score.

Comment: It says I can do that in 2 days. And thanks for editing.

Comment: Sounds good! And, you’re welcome!